# How can I make a sidebar 100% in height between header and footer using bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my sidebar display full height between the header and footer when page content is smaller the the screen view. Is this even possible using bootstrap. I am unable to find any solution that works. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
  html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin-bottom: 75px;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    height: 75px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #303030;
    color: white;
} 

 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm" style="background-color: #303030;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" title="Home">MyLogo</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100" style="border: 2px solid red;">
      <div class="col-3" style="border: 2px solid blue;">
        <p>vertical navigation</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-9">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
          Adipisci error vel recusandae minus ea atque non vitae dolorem commodi dolores 
          nostrum, est reiciendis maxime ab sit aliquid! Aliquam, modi natus.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap will have certain classes whose properties are strictly not to be changed.

I have introduced a new class called `full-screen` which will use 100 percent height of your viewport by using `100vh` then I subtracted the height of your `header` and `footer` by using `calc(100vh - 131px)` where `131px` is your `header + footer` height.

I am pretty sure this will work on all screen sizes given that you have fixed header and footer sizes all time. In case the height of header or footer changes just recalculate manually and replace 131px to whatever number you calculate and adjust until you don't see a scroll.

Demo link: https://jsfiddle.net/awesomestvi/7gxqa265/10/

Comment: You can probably use flexbox to avoid the use of calc...

Comment: I agree, that's one way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but unfortuneately when adding more content the footer no longer stays at the bottom. Demo Link: https://jsfiddle.net/kiekar/c2vo49b8/6/

Comment: I have fixed the issue. Changed height to min-height so it does not get affected by the content of the body. https://jsfiddle.net/awesomestvi/7gxqa265/10/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/cjrzL6qa/

Comment: I added the height of 100% but unfortunately a scroll bar appears. When I scroll down, the footer is now pushed up with a gap at the bottom of  50px

Answer (score 0):

i know why!!! remove from line 6 in html the "h-100", and it will work...

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions but unfortunately it's not working https://jsfiddle.net/kiekar/30x69fLh/3/

Comment: i know why!!! remove from line 6 in html the "h-100", and it will work...<div class="container-fluid h-100">

Comment: Thank You Yarin. It's close but not exactly what I'm looking for. When I removed most of the content I have a white space below the footer. I'm looking to have the footer always at the bottom( not sticky footer using bootstrap) regardless  of the amount of content Demo Links: https://jsfiddle.net/kiekar/30x69fLh/9/